# How / why do function definitions in Haskell with functions of the LHS and the RHS work?

Tags: haskell

I'm learning Haskell from Hutton's book "Programming in Haskell" (2nd ed.). At the beginning of ch. 7, "Higher-order functions", the function 'twice' is defined as:

```
twice :: (a -> a) -> a -> a
twice f x = f (f x)
```

Then a few usage examples are given, e.g.:

```
> twice reverse [1,2,3]
[1,2,3]
```

Then the author says that "the fact that reversing a (finite) list twice has no effect is captured by the equation *twice reverse = id*..."
When I start ghci and write:

```
GHCi, version 8.4.4: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> :type twice

<interactive>:1:1: error: Variable not in scope: twice
Prelude> twice reverse = id
Prelude> :type twice
twice :: p -> a -> a
Prelude> twice reverse [1,2,3]
[1,2,3]
```

This actually works as a function definition as *twice* is not previously defined. Now, my question is how that works? Is *twice reverse* just defined as an alias for *id*? But if so why can I query the type of *twice* in isolation? Which are the relevant parts of the Haskell language report for explaining this kind of function definition syntax? Also, why is the type variable *p* used? Normally *a, b etc.* are used.

**Edit**

Thanks for the helpful answers an comments, so far!

I just want to provide a little more background regarding the other questions I asked that have not been addressed. Of course, the most important questions have already been answered.

*Why is one of the type variables called p?*

Let's have a look at the following ghci session:

```
GHCi, version 8.4.4: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> twice asdf fsda = id
Prelude> :type twice
twice :: p1 -> p2 -> a -> a
Prelude> mySum a b c d = a + c
Prelude> :type mySum
mySum :: Num a => a -> p1 -> a -> p2 -> a
```

It seems that *p* or *p1, p2 etc.* are used as generic types for variables that are not used. Maybe they are also used for other purposes. I found a hint in an [article](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/8gnpj3/help_with_understanding_generics/) on another Q&A forum. Which names are used for generic type variables might even be implementation specific. The important take away message is that it does not matter which letters are used because what matters is that they differ.

*Which are the relevant parts of the language specification?*

Probably ch. 4.4.3, "Function and Pattern Bindings", in the 2010 Haskell Language Report. But that's too much information for me right now. After all I'm somewhere in the first half of an introductory Haskell book.

Comment: Hint: try changing `twice reverse = id` to `twice esrever = id`.

Comment: Ah okay, so the title of my question is already wrong: there are no functions on the LHS.

Comment: @DanBeck: everything at the left side that starts with a lowercase is a *variable* (except of course the function you define itself).

Comment: @DanBeck: You can however specify "rewrite rules" to optimize code: https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.0.3/docs/html/users_guide/rewrite-rules.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let’s step through what you’re doing here. First, you define:

```
twice :: (a -> a) -> a -> a
twice f x = f (f x)
```

This is a normal function definition, and works as you would expect: `twice (+1) 2 = 3`, `twice reverse "abc" = "abc"` etc. When Hutton says that ‘the fact that reversing a (finite) list twice has no effect is captured by the equation `twice reverse = id`’, he is simply saying that `twice reverse` has the same effect as doing `id`.

But then, you define:

```
twice reverse = id
```

This does not do what you would expect! You might expect this to validate whether the equation `twice reverse = id` holds, or something similar. But instead, this defines a totally new function `twice`, names its sole argument `reverse`, and then ignores that argument and returns the `id` function. Here, you are using *shadowing*: you are defining a new identifier (in this case `reverse`) with the same name as an old identifier. And in fact, if you enable all warnings with `-Wall`, GHC will warn you about this:

```
Prelude> :set -Wall
Prelude> twice reverse = id

<interactive>:2:7: warning: [-Wname-shadowing]
    This binding for `reverse' shadows the existing binding
      imported from `Prelude' (and originally defined in `GHC.List')
```

So defining `twice reverse = id` is no different to defining a function `twice myArg = id`, other than the fact that the argument has a different name.

Comment: Hi, that's a great answer. Now I understand the semantics of what I was doing in the ghci session. Thanks a lot!